# java jar file reading image file

Tags: java, spring, email, embedded-resource

i have stand alone application, which has one of the module to sent out emails. This application packaged as executable JAR containing all the resource files including images.

I am using spring for sending email, which contains following code for inline:

Spring code is using ***org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource***

```
//IN-LINE ATTCHEMENTS
                if (null != msg.getInlineAttachments() && msg.getInlineAttachments().size() > 0) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, File> e : msg.getInlineAttachments().entrySet()) {
                        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
                            log.trace("Conntent-ID:" + e.getKey() + ", Resource:" + e.getValue());
                        }
                        try {
                            helper.addInline(e.getKey(), new FileSystemResource(e.getValue()));
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            log.error(e1);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

File image is passed to above code using following:

```
    ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("./images/" + name);
    if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
        log.trace(res.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
    file = res.getFile();
```

**Note:**
Application works fine when executed in development environment in eclipse, because it is exploded format, non-jar.

**Exception:**

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [images/app_logo.png] 
cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system:
 jar:file:/C:/TEMP/app-1.0/app-1.0.jar!/images/app_logo.png
```

Comment: can you try to use the ClassPathResource without converting it to a File. Then it should work from a JAR.

Comment: no luck with this change too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only option left out is copy image files into temp folder, and reference from there...

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the image as a Stream instead of a File. Files are concept that are only valid in a filesystem, but you are trying to access something inside of a Jar which isn't a filesystem.

Comment: *"You need to handle the image as a Stream"* ..or URL.. *"instead of a File."*

Comment: i have tried with InputStreamSource object from ClassPathResource, to pass InputStream, but still does not find.

Comment: Inside your jar where is the file?

Comment: Inside JAR file two major folders com and resources /resources/images/img001.png ...

Comment: Then this line is incorrect:  ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("./images/" + name);

It should be:  ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("/resources/images/" + name);